# How can I protect an account using multisig?

Tags: accounts, multisig

I'd like to create a new account using cleos that requires multiple signatures to perform owner and active authorizations. I tried the following but it didn't quite work.

`./cleos set account permission testmultisig owner {"threshold":"2","keys":[{"key":"EOS8Re9txzHLCjtS1Hnkfnocgf4pPpQQqn2WXeQjAgLfWdoSR2bSQ","weight":"1"},{"key":"EOS7hFephCDUVDE8mcuBUhY9yEyBJ1VcFMBDktivhWHK9BD1Xd7yx","weight":"1"}],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"testmultisig","permission":"owner"},"weight":"2"}]}`

Comment: What error did you get? I think you should quote the JSON part.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It would be nice if you could post the result of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I skim your command I found that you forgot ' ' in the permission setting.

./cleos set account permission testmultisig owner **'**{"threshold":"2","keys":[{"key":"EOS8Re9txzHLCjtS1Hnkfnocgf4pPpQQqn2WXeQjAgLfWdoSR2bSQ","weight":"1"},{"key":"EOS7hFephCDUVDE8mcuBUhY9yEyBJ1VcFMBDktivhWHK9BD1Xd7yx","weight":"1"}],"accounts":[{"permission":"actor":"testmultisig","permission":"owner"},"weight":"2"}]}**'**